# C++ Makefile Dependencies: What Files Do Object Files Depend On?

Tags: c++, makefile, dependencies

I'm a little confused on the Makefile dependencies for .cpp files. For example, say I have a file main.cpp that includes Point.h and Rectangle.h. I would think that the Makefile dependency line for main.o looks like:

main.o: main.cpp

But it seems most people would do:

main.o: main.cpp Point.h Rectangle.h

I don't understand why. Object files are created before linking, right? So when main.cpp is compiled to main.o, its references to Point and Rectangle functions are still unresolved references, in a way. Then, when making the final executable, the linker resolves the references with the machine code for Point and Rectangle. In other words, main.o doesn't really get impacted if I change Point.h or Rectangle.h. The final executable does depend on all three, but main.o does not. What is wrong with my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your `Point.h` header file defines a class as follows:

```
class Point {

    int x;

    int y;

    int hash() const
    {
          return x+y;
    }
};
```

The class may have other stuff in it, or some other class method. This is just an example.

Your `main.cpp` calls the `hash()` method of some `Point`. And you compile it.

Now you go back, and edit this header file:

```
    int hash() const
    {
          return x*y;
    }
```

You don't change anything in `main.cpp`.

But you obviously must recompile it, since it's now supposed to be doing something different, since it calls `hash()`.

Pretty much ***any*** kind of change in the header file potentially affects any `.cpp` file that includes it, hence they all must be recompiled.

An `#include` is logically equivalent to replacing the line with the `#include` with the entire contents of the included file.

So, if you change anything in the header file, it is logically equivalent to changing something in the `.cpp` file that includes it. It is ***the compiled code*** in the `main.o` that's affected by it, and not just the final executable. Here, you'll just relink the same code in `main.o` that still uses the definition of `hash()` that you already changed now.

Comment: I don't understand why main.o must be recompiled. The main.o compiled code doesn't contain the machine code for hash(), right? It just contains a reference to hash(). The machine code for hash() doesn't get linked until later, right?

Comment: It certainly contains code for `hash()`, because you're only linking `main.o`, and  nothing else. If it's not in `main.o`, where do you think it is? The linker is not going to create code out of thin air, and link it with whatever else is in `main.o`. You also need to focus on the part of my answer that explains what `#include` is, and how it works. Everything in a header file, once it gets included from a `.cpp`, is as if it was in the `.cpp` to start with and the header file did not exist. That's how C++ works. So, if you change that code, you must recompile it.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!